# Cannot assign data from mysql to session array

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a checklogin page and followin codes;

```
$sql = "select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
{
    $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count++;
}
if ($count == 1) 
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = "true";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['usertype'] = $line['type'];
}
```

And the $_SESSION['usertype'] is always 1 even though it is different in database, what am I doing wrong

Comment: What happens if you dump $line?

Comment: Do you have `session_start` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you do a little debugging through the entire process.

- Verify that `$username` and `$password` are what you expect them to be before you run the query:

  ```
  echo "Username: {$username} Password: {$password}<br/>";
  ```
- Verify that your query is returning the right values:

  ```
  $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($line);
  echo "</pre>";
  ```
- If both of those tests return the expected values, then you may have to investigate your session - is it being started properly? Is it being reset somewhere?

Comment: Thank you Sam, it helped me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$line is returning 1 because it is a boolean yes/no result. A result was found hence it returns 1.

You have to iterate through $line or access result set #1 directly with $line[0]['type'];

Or just fetch a single row:

Taken from the manual:

```
**Example #1 Fetching one row with mysql_fetch_row()**
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

In you case, if you changed your select to "select type from users .... " instead of "select *"

```
$line[0]
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns a single row in an associative array, *or* it returns false if there are no more rows.  It never returns `true`

Comment: Dah! that'll teach me to post untested code! Not sure of the protocol for posting incorrect advice - so will leave my answer as is.